# Render local variables in partials with Ajax, Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble getting my local variables to display inside the partials after the Ajax call. Here is my setup:

**View** - *index.html.erb*

```
<% @artists.each do |artist| %>
  <div class="index_follow_button">
    <%= render "partials/index_follow_button", :artist => artist %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**View** *partials/_index_follow_button.html.erb*

```
<% if fan_signed_in? %>
  <% if fan_signed_in? && current_fan.following_artist?(artist) %>
    <%= button_to "unfollow", artist_relationship_path(artist, current_fan.artist_relationship_id(artist)), method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <% elsif fan_signed_in? %>
    <%= form_for(ArtistRelationship.new, url: artist_relationships_path(artist), remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "follow" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**View** - *follow_button.js.erb*

```
$('.index_follow_button').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/index_follow_button.html.erb', :locals => {:artist => artist}) %>');
```

**I believe this is where the error is**

**Controller** - *relationships_controller.rb*

```
def create
  @relationship = ArtistRelationship.new
  @relationship.fan_id = current_fan.id
  @relationship.artist_id = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id]).id
  @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id])
  if @relationship.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to (:back) }
      format.js { render :action => "follow_button" }
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def destroy
  current_fan.unfollow_artist(Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id]))
  @artist = Artist.friendly.find(params[:artist_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to (:back) }
    format.js { render :action => "follow_button" }
  end
end
```

In the index page, the partial displays perfectly fine using `:artist => artist`, but the same thing is not happening in the JavaScript page, but I keep getting the same error -

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `artist' for #<#<Class:0x3798df8>:0x6f43968>)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artist is a local variable but in your js file it's unset (unless you left some code out).  Instead try to use the instance variable:
follow_button.js.erb:

```
$('.index_follow_button').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/index_follow_button.html.erb', :locals => {:artist => @artist}) %>');
```

In your index.html.erb your loop sets the local variable `artist`.

---

Looks like you also need a unique way for jquery to address the element in question.

```
<% @artists.each do |artist| %>
  <div class="index_follow_button" id="artist-<%= artist.id %>">
    <%= render "partials/index_follow_button", :artist => artist %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then once again change follow_button.js.erb; this time to use the new id as the css locator instead of the class.

```
$('#artist-<%= @artist.id %>').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render 
  :partial => 'partials/index_follow_button.html.erb', 
  :locals => {:artist => artist}) %>'
);
```

Comment: This does not work as clicking the `follow` button causes every single `follow` button on the `index.html.erb` page to be converted to `unfollow`.

Comment: do they all have the same html class of `.index_follow_button` ?  I suspect your jquery call is overwriting each element with that class.

Comment: Ah, you are right! What is the proper way to have only the one being clicked change?

Comment: You need something unique; then you can set the id of the element and use that in jquery.  Is the artist unique?  or could you use the artist.id?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `@artist` variable in your follow_button.js.erb file.

`$('.index_follow_button').html('<%=  escape_javascript(render :partial => 'partials/index_follow_button.html.erb', :locals => {:artist => @artist}) %>');`

Comment: Nice Saiqul, beat me by 12 seconds!

Comment: This does not work as clicking the `follow` button causes every single `follow` button on the `index.html.erb` page to be converted to `unfollow`.

Comment: Actually I wanna to reply this question 20 minutes ago, but I was busy, haha

Comment: it's `@artists = Artist.all`, but after Ajax is called in the `relationships_controller` isn't everything used from there?